# Template and Attribute tag is not getting added to the kendo grid column at a time

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to right align all the numeric columns. Also I have added a format to the column for 2 decimal places. But it is not supporting format and template simultaneously. Template is overriding the format. 
Here is my code

column['template'] = "#= " + kendo.format("{0:n2}", dataFields[fieldIndex]) + " #";

column['format'] = '{0:n2}';

Here if I am adding template to the column then formatting is not working.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this.
I have added a class to the template and after grid load I have formatted the data using this class name by jquery